# Moderation for NSFW topics

Tags: discussion, moderation

I recently came across a question on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) asking what the first known pornographic video game/software/etc. was (wasn't able to find that particular question).  A comment on there asked if there were moderation for such NSFW topics. This question (and others I have found, like [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49990/what-are-the-technical-contributions-of-the-pornography-industry), or [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136711/would-working-for-an-adult-website-hurt-my-future-employability)) promoted legitimate answers.

I don't ever foreshadow that this forum will begin to include adult content, but I believe it would be a good idea to moderate for it. Imagine your boss walking by and sees **pornography** included in the title of the question you are reading.

Comment: The question was deleted, probably because it was gathering offensive flags even after it was closed, the link for 10K+ users is http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/150043/what-was-the-first-pornographic-software-program.

Comment: I've edited out the [feature-request] tag because you aren't really asking for a specific feature to be implemented. If you have a feature in mind please add it to the question and add the tag again.

Comment: @YannisRizos The `moderation` tag fits better than `feature-request`. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well in a way we do moderate for offensive and objectionable material on the site so I am sure that if one of my fellow mods were to come across porn they would quickly remove it and take appropriate action against the user.

As far as the wording and title of the questions are considered, I would probably seek and encourage less than explicit ways to convey the questions and answers, especially the title.  Many of us go to the Stack Exchange sites while we are at work and many of us happen to work in offices that have content filtering of objectionable and lewd material.  The most common of these is site blacklisting but some of the more sensitive software packages out there will go so far as scanning documents for the prevalence of key words.

The word "Pornography" seems safe.  Describing in explicit detail a pornographic story or scene is more than likely not relevant to any ontopic conversation on this site anyway so it can be promptly removed.

We also try to moderate by removing curse words as well, at least I do.  I want the site to be as family friendly as possible.

The bottom line is that our users are the front line of moderation on this site.  Our active users take the initiative to promptly flag material that needs our attention and are not afraid to edit questions and answers or approve edits to questions and answers where they feel is appropriate.

Moderation on this site can be directly attributed to these individuals, you guys know who you are, I see your names all the time in the flag queue so keep up the good work ;-)

**EDIT:**  On a somewhat unrelated note, if you think we have a problem with this you should check out Skeptics on the sexuality tag.  It's like the backroom of the video rental store :)

Comment: A quality answer.  I am a part of other SE sites and notice how well the rules of each forum are enforced by all. Sometimes, there's the back and forth irrelevant bickering that takes place, but never anything that's over-the-top (perhaps due to front-line moderation). My question used adult content as an example, but there are other topics out there. Regardless, **family-friendly** sums it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We should be able to talk about subjects as adults and not have breakdowns, because someone used the word pornography or sex or some other word deemed offensive by someone. The particular question you ask about probably was off topic, but there are plenty of questions related to programming history that could legitimately involve talking about pornographic sites. These questions should be allowed to exist and prosper along with all the others, IMO we would be doing a disservice to the site and all users if we were to ban uncomfortable but on topic questions.

Finally talking about pornography or a subject in which pornography is related is an entirely different thing than having pictures/videos/stories/whatever. Even 13 year-olds should be capable of speaking in a civilized fashion about things like pornography's contribution to the internet as we know it today,  and is a perfectly family-friendly discussion.

Comment: I disagree whole-heartedly. Stack Exchange should not be a network where adults can preform Q&A style learning. It should be a site where anyone over the age of 13 (minimum sign up age) can preform in Q&A style learning. So _family-friendly_ is the key here.

Comment: @Dynamic check out my edit.

Comment: In what family is porn family friendly?

Comment: Adult Content was the example that brought on my question. The role technology has on porn is what makes it a billion dollar industry today.....that's worthy of legitimate and educational discussion **related to programming/sw dev history**. How would we, as a community, feel if a 13 yr old gets involved with a pornographic medium because of the reference of this forum? This is why **family-friendly** is key. Nobody's doubting the role of technology in porn, but this is a forum dedicated to programming and software development Q&A, not a repository for NSFW resources.

Comment: -1: *Even 13 year-olds should be capable of speaking in a civilized fashion about things like pornography's contribution to the internet as we know it today, and is a perfectly family-friendly discussion.* - You can encourage *your* 13-year-old to participate in such discussions, but please keep her away from my 13-year-old.

Comment: @JimG. I have to agree with you.  I don't know a 13 year old in the world that can have an intelligent and civilized discussion about pornography.  Not until they are at least 16 are they mentally and emotionally capable of holding or understanding such conversations.

Comment: I think you guys are getting hung up on the pornography part, a discussion about pornography is not what I'm talking about (and would be off topic). I am saying a 13 year old can talk about X which happens to be pioneered by Y, where Y happens to be the pornography industry. Its like talking about the history of manufacturing and commenting how Ford revolutionized manufacturing with his implementation of the assembly line, its not about Fords or even cars, its about manufacturing.

Comment: +1. A discussion about the technical contributions of the pornography industry is not at all the same as a discussion about pornography. I see no reason why a technically astute youngster could not have a conversation about the former. And I think most of the downvoters are misreading what Ryathal is saying.

Comment: To a 13-yr old programmer, porn sites could be an excellent source of revenue. Family-friendly or not is irrelevant.